# Docker config angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

Sorry for my english. I new docker and for me now it not easy. I want configurate this project:

Then i added two files

[image]

my docker-compose

```
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - '49153:49153'
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
        - NODE_ENV=dev
    command: bash -c "npm start"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.6 as node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g angular-cli
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 49153

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Then i run like this:

```
docker-compose build
```

and

```
docker-compose up
```

My question: haw i correct write settings to Docker? In console when i do `docker-compose build` message

```
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '8.6.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.6.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.6.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.6.0
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.6.0
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.6.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting on to answer your question:

1. You don't need "angular-cli" dependency in your app package for it to run. So you should remove it from Dockerfile.
2. Add a .dockerignore file and add the below line in it -

   node_modules

   npm-debug.log

   This will prevent your local modules and debug logs from being copied onto your Docker image and possibly overwriting modules installed within your image.

I see you trying to use [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) in your Dockerfile with just one stage in it. The below is screenshot of my Dockerfile for the [angular quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) sample 
[image]